# How to pass a javascript variable to an html form action tag

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have an html form which contain name, longitude and latitude text field. The longitude and latitude are stored in a javascript variable. Do you know how post the name, latitude and longitude to a server, I mean via a url? Everytime I am submitting the form, the longitude and latitude are not passed into the url? Can anyone please tell me how to do that?

Thank you

This is my code for both my javascript and html:

```
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
    var geolocation = {};
    geolocation.latitude = 0;
    geolocation.longitude = 0;
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (p) {
    geolocation.latitude = p.coords.latitude;
    geolocation.longitude = p.coords.longitude;           
    }, function (error) {
    alert("Failed to get GPS location");
    });
    } else {
    alert("Failed to get GPS working");
    }

    function loc() {
    document.getElementById("longitude").value = geolocation.latitude;
    document.getElementById("latitude").value = geolocation.longitude;

    }
```

html:

```
    <form name="photo" method="post" action="url">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="Text1" value="" />
    <label for="longitude">Longitude:</label>
    <input type="text" name="longitude" id="longitude" />
    <label for="latitude">Latitude:</label>
    <input type="text" name="latitude" id="latitude" />
    <label for="image">Image:</label>
    <input type="text" name="image" id="image" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

Comment: Let's see the HTML for the form, plus whatever JavaScript code you already have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the action of the form you need to mention the name of the servlet you want to call. Make use of three hidden fields to store the values name, longitude and latitude. This can be done using

`document.getElementById('hiddenFieldId1').value=longitude;`
 `document.getElementById('hiddenFieldId2').value=latitude;`
 `document.getElementById('hiddenFieldId3').value=name;`

These values can be referred in the servlet using `request.getParameter('hiddenFieldId');`

You need to submit the form in your js:

`document.myform.submit();`

`geolocation` variable hasn't been made global, so it is not defined in your function `loc()`. There are no values assigned to `geolocation.latitude` and `geolocation.longitude`.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Do you mean that geolocation variable should be outside the IF statement. If not, can you please give me an example code of how to do it? Thank you

Comment: this declaration `var geolocation = {};` should be made outside the if.

Comment: Thanks for ur help once again, in which part of my code do I put this "document.getElementById('hiddenFieldId1').value=longitude; document.getElementById('hiddenFieldId2').value=latitude; document.getElementById('hiddenFieldId3').value=name;"? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could add elements to the form...

```
var myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');

var longitude = document.createElement('input');
longitude.name= 'longitude';
longitude.value = '100';

var latitude= document.createElement('input');
latitude.name= 'latitude';
latitude.value = '100';

myForm.appendChild(longitude);
myForm.appendChild(latitude);
```